# Angular encodes url in ng-src and replaces '/' with %2F and '?' with %3F

Tags: javascript, angularjs, encoding, kibana, urlencode

I have a Kibana dashboard with URL:

```
/logquery/app/kibana#/dashboard/Some-Dashboard?someParameters
```

and I have a web application in which I am trying to embed the dashboard above in an `<iframe>`. The url in the web application is as follows

```
/dashboards/logquery/app/kibana#/dashboard/Some-Dashboard?someParameters
```

and in AngularJs, I am doing:

```
ctrl.dashboardUrl = $location.url().replace('/dashboards', '');
```

In my view:

```
<div ng-controller="DashboardCtrl as ctrl">
    <div class="iframe-container">
        <iframe ng-src="{{ctrl.dashboardUrl | trustAsUrl}}"
                height="100%"
                width="100%"
                ng-cloak
                frameborder="0"
                marginheight="0"
                marginwidth="0"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

`trustAsUrl` filter is as follows:

```
filtersGroup.filter('trustAsUrl', [
    '$sce',
    function ($sce) {
        return function (val) {
            return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(val);
        };
    }]);
```

and I have:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled: true,
                requireBase: false,
                rewriteLinks: false
            });
```

This causes `/` characters after `/kibana#` to be replaced with `%2F` and `?` with `%3F` which causes Kibana not to be able to find the requested dashboard.

How can I overcome this? Thanks!

Comment: then do not use `trustAsUrl` filter,
`ng-src="{{ctrl.dashboardUrl}}"`

Comment: @MirazChowdhury It doesn't make a difference. To my knowledge, it is not the part which encodes the dashboard url.

Comment: Can you please add your code on fiddle?

Comment: Have you tried to simply decode it? `return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(decodeURIComponent (val));`

Comment: This is what's happening, the page opens with the correct URL in the address bar, then angular modifies the URL and encodes the url, then `DashboardCtrl` reads the url with `$location` service and I get the encoded URL. I guess what I have to do is to disable Angular from encoding the URL in the address bar once the page opens. @masterfloda

Comment: @masterfloda I was able to simply decode the URL with pure `decodeURIComponent` method. It was actually happening not because  `trustAsResourceUrl` is encoding the URL but Angular actually manipulates what's on the address bar. If you could write a simple answer to sum the issue up, I would like to give the bounty to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is AngularJS is manipulating the URL in your address bar, which you read with `$location`.

So the problem is not happening after you read the url and put it into the `iframe` with `ngSrc` but when angular manipulates the original URL in the address bar. So you can manually decode it with [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

```
return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(decodeURIComponent(val));
```

Comment: @hasan-can-saral Thanks for the edit, great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is with `vsprintf` method which you missed in your question statement but present in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2r5s1jrb/2/) code. I modified fiddle and used javascript string interpolation instead `PHP vsprintf` method and it is returning correct URL.

Fix:

**Before**

```
vsprintf("%s://%s/%s", [$location.protocol(), $location.host(), $location.url().replace('/dashboards', '')]);
```

**After**

```
ctrl.dashboardUri = `${$location.protocol()}://${$location.host()}/${$location.url().replace('/dashboards', '')}`
```

Comment: I am sorry this is not the case. I would be surprised if `vsprintf` would have encoded the URL.

Comment: Please check the fiddle, which is without vsprintf and working perfectly

Comment: Angular will not manipulate the url in the fiddle. It works with vsprintf as well.